# Unable to attach node debugger in current version of VS code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nvm

I updated VS code to version 1.59.1 and Node debugging no longer works-- I was on a July 2020 build before today.  I use nvm to toggle between versions and my nvm default is Node 12.22.

If I run '`node --inspect-brk...`' (which I used to do) in a VS code terminal things just hang with a 'debugger listening..' message.  If I run '`node --inspect`' the program runs, also with a 'debugger listening..' message but no breakpoints are respected. (What's the difference by the way, between `inspect` and `inspect-brk`?)

After installing the latest VS code and opening it a dialog appeared saying Node 10 is in my path and so auto-attaching would no longer work.  And yes, Node 10 is part of my nvm options, but I'm using Node 12 now via nvm.  (That dialog no longer appears now when I open VS Code, for some reason.)

I have the VS code 'auto attach' setting set to 'only with flag'.  I've tried the 'always' option too but no luck.  I've closed and reopened VS code numerous times to see if a changed setting will work but it hasn't so far.  If anyone knows something I may have missed or knows what's what, I'm happy to hear suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

A couple things you can try when the auto-attach doesn't work:

- set `auto-attach` to disabled, then back on 'with flag'
- check with `env` that the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable looks something like:

  ```
  NODE_OPTIONS=--require /home/me/.vscode-server/data/User/workspaceStorage/dc520ffe0268148fad350d767ccf9350-1/ms-vscode.js-debug/bootloader.js
  ```

If not, then it helps to restart your vscode terminal, your bash, etc, until it does.

`--inspect-brk` tells NodeJS to wait for a debugger to attach before starting the program.

`--inspect` enables debugging but doesnt wait for a debugger

With vscode's auto-attach, you should use `--inspect`. It will attach automatically as soon as the program starts.

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue when I had the NODE_OPTIONS overwritten in the shell

Comment: It works (debugger auto attaches) when program is run with `--inspect`. But if program is run with `--inspect-brk` then we have to manually attach the debugger. (Using a `launch.json` file)